# C# & operator problem

Tags: c#, operator-keyword

How do I use the `&` binary operator correctly? randomSize is ushort.

```
           if (randomSize & 0x1000)
           {

           }
```

Error 5 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `if` statement expects a `bool` value, not just some non-zero value like in C/C++.  If you are checking flags, try something like this:

```
if ((randomSize & 0x1000) == 0x1000)
```